# Porting Application to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I am working on porting a J2EE application to Google App Engine.

I have tackled most of the hurdles involving the JPA relationships that App Engine does/does not support, making the distinction between static and non static files, and taking advantage of memcache instead of my handrolled cache.

My question is, how do I handle roles in the App Engine world? I have 4 roles within my application, but I'm not sure how to handle this with app engine? I see the admin role, but I'm not sure on what to do for the other roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System roles (viewer/developer/admin) have nothing to do with application/user roles.

System roles define access to GAE console and consequently to app settings and data. Users should never have direct access to any of those.

User roles have have to be provided and enforced by application code.

Comment: Right. So that's part of what I was trying to understand. When my application was deployed on JBoss, I could define roles in web.xml, persist the users in the database along with their roles in a roles table, and tell jboss how to determine what roles users are in. With GAE, since the login is done on Google's platform, I would guess that I have to now create an actual User Entity, and make the process of determining what role the user has a more manual thing, since I can no longer ask the request if the user is in a specific role.

Comment: GAE has Users service which helps you authenticate Google Apps users: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/ However once user is logged-in you will still need to handle authorisation (permission) in your code.